# opensmtpd: how to say "internal network"?

Tags: openbsd, opensmtpd

hardwired constants in my smtpd.conf are causing problems with IPv6
prefix delegation, so I wonder if there is some abbr. for "internal
network"? Something like

```
# table localnet { 10.10.10.0/24 10.10.11.0/24 2001:db8:abcd:0012::/64 }
:
listen on intern tls pki $xname
listen on extern tls pki $xname
:
action "relay" relay
# match from src <localnet> for any action "relay"
match from src (intern:network) for any action "relay"
:
```

(similar to pf.conf on OpenBSD)? "intern" would be the interface group
configured for all internal network interfaces.

I tried

```
# table localnet { 10.10.10.0/24 10.10.11.0/24 2001:db8:abcd:0012::/64 }
:
listen on intern tls pki $xname tag INTERN
listen on extern tls pki $xname tag EXTERN
:
action "relay" relay
# match from src <localnet> for any action "relay"
match tag INTERN for any action "relay"
:
```

Doesn't work :-(. If I enable the old "localnet" lines, then it does.

Hopefully I am not too blind to see, but I haven't found this in
smtpd.conf(5). Every helpful comment is highly appreciated.

Regards
Harri

Comment: OpenSMTPD isn't using anything like "intern" as something identifiable with a reserved word. This will always be something created from a configuration file macro or table. The closest you can get is to use the interface (e.g., `vio1`) that connects to the network you are writing the configuration for. This is basically the same for most system services, including `pf.conf`.

Comment: Could it be created from the interface group names, similar to pf.conf?

Comment: I've never tried it, but when you create a configuration you should always test it using the command `smtpd -n`. Also see https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/macros.html